# 'dartls -32007 file is not being analyzed' error whenever I open a file in Neovim

Tags: flutter, neovim

I am new to Neoviim. So, I am currently using Astronvim and I have setup flutter-tools plugin by following the guide [here](https://astronvim.github.io/Recipes/advanced_lsp#dart-flutter-flutter-toolsnvim).

Whenever I open a dart file I get the following error: `dartls -32007 file is not being analyzed`

Autocompletion and Fluttter commands works, but some feature like color highlights and goto definitions stops working in a dart file sometimes.

My config look like this:

```
return {
  lsp = {
    skip_setup = { "dartls" }, -- skip lsp setup because flutter-tools will do it itself
    ["server-settings"] = {
      dartls = {
        -- any changes you want to make to the LSP setup, for example
        color = {
          enabled = true,
        },
        settings = {
          showTodos = true,
          completeFunctionCalls = true,
        },
      },
    },
  },
  plugins = {
    init = {
      {
        "akinsho/flutter-tools.nvim",
        requires = "nvim-lua/plenary.nvim",
        after = "mason-lspconfig.nvim", -- make sure to load after mason-lspconfig
        config = function()
          require("flutter-tools").setup {
            lsp = astronvim.lsp.server_settings "dartls", -- get the server settings and built in capabilities/on_attach
          }
        end,
      },
    },
  },
}
```